# VBA Coding Variable Property isnt of the correct type

Tags: excel, vba

What Variable types do I need to use in order for this code to work?  I am fairly new to using VBA so I don't know how to correctly assign variables or what exactly I am doing wrong in this instance.  I have tried making all the Variables Dim As Double but that does not seem to work.  I have also tried setting them to variant and that does not seem to work either.

```
If gastype = "Carbon Monoxide (CO)" Then
LFL1 = Sheet17.Range("C3").Value
UFL1 = Sheet17.Range("C4").Value
FConchr = Sheet1.Range("O6").Value
FConcmin = Sheet1.Range("O7").Value
LFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / LFL1)
LFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / LFL1)
UFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / UFL1)
UFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / UFL1)

ElseIf gastype = "Methane (CH4)" Then
LFL1 = Sheet17.Range("E3").Value
UFL1 = Sheet17.Range("E4").Value
FConchr = Sheet1.Range("O6").Value
FConcmin = Sheet1.Range("O7").Value
LFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / LFL1)
LFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / LFL1)
UFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / UFL1)
UFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / UFL1)

ElseIf gastype = "Ammonia (NH3)" Then
LFL1 = Sheet17.Range("F3").Value
UFL1 = Sheet17.Range("F4").Value
FConchr = Sheet1.Range("O6").Value
FConcmin = Sheet1.Range("O7").Value
LFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / LFL1)
LFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / LFL1)
UFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / UFL1)
UFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / UFL1)

ElseIf gastype = "Hydrogen Sulfide (H2S)" Then
LFL1 = Sheet17.Range("H3").Value
UFL1 = Sheet17.Range("H4").Value
FConchr = Sheet1.Range("O6").Value
FConcmin = Sheet1.Range("O7").Value
LFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / LFL1)
LFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / LFL1)
UFLhr = 100 / (FConchr / UFL1)
UFLmin = 100 / (FConcmin / UFL1)
End If


Sheet1.Range("O10").Value = LFLhr
Sheet1.Range("O10").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Sheet1.Range("O10").HorizontalAlignment = x1Left

Sheet1.Range("O11").Value = LFLmin
Sheet1.Range("O11").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Sheet1.Range("O11").HorizontalAlignment = x1Left

Sheet1.Range("O12").Value = UFLhr
Sheet1.Range("O12").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Sheet1.Range("O12").HorizontalAlignment = x1Left

Sheet1.Range("O13").Value = UFLmin
Sheet1.Range("O13").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
Sheet1.Range("O13").HorizontalAlignment = x1Left
```

I have been continuing to get mismatch error 13 every time I try to set the variables to a Dim. It would be nice if someone could help me out with this and explain how to correctly assign variables so I do not have this problem again.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary

Comment: If you declare a variable as `Double`, you will get a runtime error 13 when you try to assign a string to it. When you declare the as Variant, you will not get the runtime when you assign the value, but later when you do calculations with it (a Variant can have any data type). You should check the content of your sheet.

Comment: You can also check with `IsNumber()` before doing any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The Range.Value() function returns a one-size-fits-all datatype called a Variant. This is a single type that can represents many different things: can be a string, an integer, a double, an error etc, etc.

So, without an explicit declaration, LFL1 will be of type Variant

```
LFL1 = Sheet17.Range("C3").Value
```

If cell C3 contains a number, your Variant LFL1 will contain a number. If the cell contains a string, your Variant will contain a string.

As FunThomas wrote in the comments, if you are not referring to the right cells, or those cells don't contain numbers you will run into problems.

VBA has a function called VarType() which lets you check what is in your Variant before you try and do anything with it:

```
Dim nType as Integer
v = Range("C3").Value

nType = VarType(v)

if nType = vbDouble then  'vbDouble is an enum = 5 (see VBA help on VarType)
    'you can use v as a double
else
    'v is not, alas, a double
endif
```

VBA will try and be helpful and convert the information held in the Variant into the type you want ... if it can. If the Variant contains the string "Banana", then with the best will in the world, VBA can't convert that into a double, so throws up an error.

In terms of the VarType, any type between 2 (integer) and 7 (date) inclusive can be converted to a double.

[Link to MS VBA Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009057)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Note that `.Value` can only return `String`, `Double` or `DateTime`. Cells in excel cannot contain integers `Long` type.